# Signalr remote connection error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I try to use a signalR 2 in my WebAPI application.

Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
}
```

Hub class:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task Join(string groupname)
    {
      ....
    }


    public Task Send(string groupname, string message)
    {
        ....
    }

    public Task Leave(string groupname)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And create a simple console application to use it.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://olegvolkvo-001-site2.atempurl.com/");
            var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            hubProxy.Invoke("Join", 1.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In localhost it works greate. But then I publish WebAPI project on remote hosting smarterasp.net. 
And now the client application failed with exception: AggregateException

```
{"StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type\r\n  Cache-Control: private\r\n  Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2016 22:35:22 GMT\r\n  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5\r\n  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n  Content-Length: 5016\r\n  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n}"}.
```

I try to find some information about this, but I still have this error. And I still don't understand how could it be, that in localhost everything is all right, but on remote connection it failes. 
Thanks for any advice

Comment: What's the InnerException of the AggregateException?

Comment: try calling `http://olegvolkvo-001-site2.atempurl.com/signalr/hubs` in a browser on a computer where the client fails. you should see a javascript if the server is reachable and running the hub. (the javascript should contain information about the `chatHub`)

Comment: and change the return type of the `ChatHub` methods to `void` if they aren't `async`

Comment: @stevieg, It's HttpClientException

Comment: @Dr. Fre, I see HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found on http://olegvolkvo-001-site2.atempurl.com/signalr/hubs

Comment: oh my friend take that down! I can see your not using authentication. Just worring about attack spots..(I can see your local directory and probably other stuff) But it seems like your an problem with your server setup. are you sure it's working from an other location (or did you only test it with the localhost path)?

Comment: Test it from fiddler, if it works enable cors on the server side i.e add `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` in StartUp -> Configuration method

Comment: @Ravi A. add this in Startup class. Stiil geting error

Comment: Is it working from fiddler?

Comment: @Ravi A., No, it return HTTP Not Found

Comment: Enable tracing in your console application by adding `hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;` after initializing the `HubConnection` . This will give some information on the console.